# Counting the number of distinct values of a column

Tags: sql, teradata, distinct-values

I'm running the following query with the following output....

```
   SELECT g.id,
        g.ticket,
        g.fac_id,
        Cast(g.dts AS DATE) AS dt,
        Count(DISTINCT Cast(g.dts AS DATE)) AS days_used
    FROM db1.table1 g
    INNER JOIN db2.table2 f
        ON f.fac_id = g.fac_id
        AND g.ticket = '07100103031500002'       
        AND f.loc IN (80007944, 80007838, 80007998, 80007823)
    GROUP BY g.id, g.ticket, g.fac_id, Cast(g.strt_dts AS DATE)

id  ticket  fac_id  dt  days_used
FB3CDE6B2FBE42BEA2BAD79CACA70055    07100103031500002   80,007,944  1/2/2016    1
FB3CDE6B2FBE42BEA2BAD79CACA70055    07100103031500002   80,007,823  1/3/2016    1
FB3CDE6B2FBE42BEA2BAD79CACA70055    07100103031500002   80,007,944  7/22/2018   1
FB3CDE6B2FBE42BEA2BAD79CACA70055    07100103031500002   80,007,998  1/2/2016    1
FB3CDE6B2FBE42BEA2BAD79CACA70055    07100103031500002   80,007,838  1/4/2016    1
FB3CDE6B2FBE42BEA2BAD79CACA70055    07100103031500002   80,007,944  1/3/2016    1
```

I'm trying to get the days_used column to count the distinct values in the dt column, so my days_used column should all be 4 instead of 1. Any help in changing the code? I'm hoping to just change the select structure for deriving days_used if possible.

Comment: Are the first four columns already unique or do you need that Group By as replacement for DISTINCT??

Answer (score 0):

What you really want is:

```
    Count(DISTINCT Cast(g.dts AS DATE)) over () AS days_used
```

But Teradata doesn't support `count(distinct)` with window functions.  So you can use:

```
select . . .,
       sum(case when seqnum = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as num_different_dates
from (select . . .,
             row_number() over (partition by Cast(g.dts AS DATE) order by g.dts) as seqnum
      from db1.table1 g join
           db2.table2 f
           on f.fac_id = g.fac_id and
              g.ticket = '07100103031500002' and    
              f.loc IN (80007944, 80007838, 80007998, 80007823)
     ) gf
. . .
```

Comment: This will also return `1` instead of `4`, as `partition by` is missing in the `row_number`

Answer (score 0):

As Gordon already explained you need to rewrite `COUNT(DISTINCT) OVER` with two Window-functions.

A way to get the expected result without nesting in a Derived Table is based on differently ordered `DENSE_RANKs`:

```
DENSE_RANK() over (order by Cast(g.dts AS DATE) ) +
DENSE_RANK() over (order by Cast(g.dts AS DATE) DESC) - 1
```

In your case it's:

```
FB3CDE6B2FBE42BEA2BAD79CACA70055    07100103031500002   80,007,944  1/2/2016    1   1+4-1=4 
FB3CDE6B2FBE42BEA2BAD79CACA70055    07100103031500002   80,007,998  1/2/2016    1   1+4-1=4
FB3CDE6B2FBE42BEA2BAD79CACA70055    07100103031500002   80,007,823  1/3/2016    1   2+3-1=4
FB3CDE6B2FBE42BEA2BAD79CACA70055    07100103031500002   80,007,944  1/3/2016    1   2+3-1=4
FB3CDE6B2FBE42BEA2BAD79CACA70055    07100103031500002   80,007,838  1/4/2016    1   3+2-1=4
FB3CDE6B2FBE42BEA2BAD79CACA70055    07100103031500002   80,007,944  7/22/2018   1   4+1-1=4
```

Comment: Are you saying that adding those two lines to my select of my original code will give me the desired output?

Comment: Because that's giving me an error that says "Syntax error: expected something between the 'DATE' keyword and the 'DESC' keyword."

Comment: Wrong parens, fixed.